# Geth - Block sealing stopped in POA network

Tags: go-ethereum, poa, geth-clique

New block sealing is stopped in PoA network with 3 nodes. Transactions are always going into **pending** state. Though the nodes were synced, blocks are never synced after block#69400 for new transactions. Getting error for new transactions -

```
Transaction receipt was not generated after 600 seconds for transaction.
```

**What could be the possible reason? I have shared the latest logs of the nodes.**

[image: Network monitor]

**Node 1 logs**

```
WARN [04-26|05:28:17.730] Served eth_getFilterChanges              conn=172.20.20.24:52468 reqid=1742391 t=95.01µs    err="filter not found"
WARN [04-26|05:28:18.231] Served eth_getFilterChanges              conn=172.20.20.24:52472 reqid=1742392 t=57.535µs   err="filter not found"
INFO [04-26|05:28:18.266] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x327a06695c5cb6d290fe9298b6940430c7cf1404e4adc68c105e37d92d454193 recipient=0x7005b9BbAF0336fB545742cA458543b592e7EDd1
INFO [04-26|05:28:18.279] Commit new mining work                   number=69403 sealhash=03ded5…75dfbd uncles=0 txs=2    gas=262943 fees=0.005784746 elapsed=12.880ms
INFO [04-26|05:28:18.279] Signed recently, must wait for others
WARN [04-26|05:28:18.731] Served eth_getFilterChanges              conn=172.20.20.24:52483 reqid=1742393 t=62.054µs   err="filter not found"
WARN [04-26|05:28:19.233] Served eth_getFilterChanges              conn=172.20.20.24:52487 reqid=1742394 t=93.738µs   err="filter not found"
```

**Node 2 logs**

```
INFO [04-26|05:00:37.631] Imported new chain segment               blocks=2    txs=2    mgas=2.922   elapsed=63.705ms  mgasps=45.860  number=69400 hash=5005a2…3a38a5 age=1mo1w4d   dirty=255.81MiB
INFO [04-26|05:02:26.019] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1000000000
INFO [04-26|05:02:26.019] Commit new mining work                   number=69401 sealhash=0ae800…cceaac uncles=0 txs=0    gas=0 fees=0 elapsed=213.597µs
INFO [04-26|05:02:26.020] Sealing paused, waiting for transactions
INFO [04-26|05:02:57.008] Commit new mining work                   number=69401 sealhash=e943ab…40467a uncles=0 txs=1    gas=205318 fees=0.004516996 elapsed=7.916ms
INFO [04-26|05:02:57.015] Successfully sealed new block            number=69401 sealhash=e943ab…40467a hash=b5df5d…2b9f0d elapsed=7.035ms
INFO [04-26|05:02:57.015]  mined potential block                  number=69401 hash=b5df5d…2b9f0d
INFO [04-26|05:02:57.017] Commit new mining work                   number=69402 sealhash=ef125c…a3b50c uncles=0 txs=0    gas=0      fees=0           elapsed=1.661ms
INFO [04-26|05:02:57.017] Sealing paused, waiting for transactions
INFO [04-26|05:03:27.749] Commit new mining work                   number=69402 sealhash=583257…0efe58 uncles=0 txs=1    gas=57661  fees=0.001268542 elapsed=5.671ms
INFO [04-26|05:03:27.749] Signed recently, must wait for others
INFO [04-26|05:04:00.290] Commit new mining work                   number=69402 sealhash=72f887…b1097b uncles=0 txs=2    gas=115322 fees=0.002537084 elapsed=5.204ms
INFO [04-26|05:04:00.290] Signed recently, must wait for others
INFO [04-26|05:28:18.262] Commit new mining work                   number=69402 sealhash=bc479d…4be1b8 uncles=0 txs=3    gas=320604 fees=0.007053288 elapsed=7.759ms
INFO [04-26|05:28:18.262] Signed recently, must wait for others
```

**Node 3 logs**

```
INFO [04-26|05:25:09.804] Imported new state entries               count=382  elapsed=8.267ms   processed=996251 pending=0     retry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=384
INFO [04-26|05:25:09.805] Imported new block receipts              count=0    elapsed=373.576µs number=69337 hash=74725d…04ff6c age=1mo1w4d size=0.00B     ignored=1
INFO [04-26|05:25:09.806] Committed new head block                 number=69337 hash=74725d…04ff6c
INFO [04-26|05:25:09.895] Deallocated fast sync bloom              items=8852801 errorrate=0.000
INFO [04-26|05:25:11.559] Imported new chain segment               blocks=65 txs=65 mgas=94.149 elapsed=1.659s    mgasps=56.748 number=69402 hash=982004…72cc3f age=2m7s    dirty=11.25MiB
INFO [04-26|05:25:11.968] Fast sync complete, auto disabling
INFO [04-26|05:25:32.834] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1000000000
INFO [04-26|05:25:32.835] Commit new mining work                   number=69403 sealhash=22e6ff…031ce7 uncles=0 txs=0  gas=0 fees=0 elapsed=317.977µs
INFO [04-26|05:25:32.836] Sealing paused, waiting for transactions
```